# Firefox, the cookie monster?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, firefox, cookies

I'm having some problems with being logged out at least once a day. Whilst I'm slowly trying to debug the issue I noticed that Firefox isn't happy with some of the cookies in chat.

1. Go to your favourite chat room. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/
2. Right Click > Inspect Element > Console
3. At the very top you should see something like the following. (if you expand the top message)

**Note**: I do not see this on non-chat pages.

```
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “sameSite“ attribute 20
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite the-2nd-monitor
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite events
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite counters
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite 8595
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite 8595
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite ws-auth
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite info
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite 2 new
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite ack
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite ack
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite ack
 Cookie “.ASPXBrowserOverride” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
 Cookie “sechatusr” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite new
```

Comment: @Mithical I can repro this with no scripts running in that same chat *and* other chats on chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have 'Some cookies are misusing the recommended “sameSite“ attribute' errors [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399131/3404097).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Adding to `status-deferred` so we can address in the future. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firefox should be happy once again. The `.ASPXBrowserOverride` cookie is no longer being served. Fun fact: we resolved this issue on the whole network back in October 2012. Here is the fix, just 'cause:

[image: Screen shot of the code change to remove this unneeded cookie]

Also resolved the issue with the auth cookie not being set to have `Secure=true`.

---

> cookies taste so good
> unneeded ones, however,
> should just not be served

Comment: I still get some of them, specifically on `quant.js:2:1359` (3) and `analytics.js:30:386` (3)

Comment: If it was fixed in *October 2012* then why could the user report it in July 2020? Am I misunderstanding something from the timelines or is the fix from 2012 the reason  this bug appeared?

Comment: @rene It was fixed on the network in 2012. It was fixed on chat today.

Comment: Ah, Now that makes sense. Thanks for unblurring me for a moment.